# How Hibernate distincts object type with InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have different user types in my Spring app. I implemented some kind of Inheritance. All users types extends from User class. I think two tables should be enough here:

1. table "users" - contains columns for all shared entity attributes
2. table "users_corporate" - contains columns for CorporateCustomer class attriburtes: companyName and VatNumber

"users" will have: id, username, password, first_name, last_name, email, mobile, city, street, postcode

"users_corporate" will have: company_name, vat_number

Class RetailCustomer and Provider doesn't have any fields with @Column annotation so there is no need to have table for them, I only need to declare fields with OneToMany mappings..
Now I'm wondering how hibernate will distinct Provider and RetailCustomer from each other if I don't have @Table annotation in their class. When I will use Spring Data repository and for example call providerRepository.findAll() how it will now which rows from "users" table are provider and which are retailCustomer? Will it work? Am I missing something?

BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

}
```

CorporateCustomer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_corporate")
public class CorporateCustomer extends User{

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "vat_number")
    private String vatNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Appointment> appointments;
}
```

RetailCustomer:

```
@Entity
//@Table  <---- i think it is not needed here?
public class RetailCustomer extends User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Appointment> appointments;
}
```

Provider:

```
@Entity
//@Table  <---- i think it is not needed here?
public class Provider extends User{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "provider")
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="works_providers", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_user"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_work"))
    private List<Work> works;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="provider", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private WorkingPlan workingPlan;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How hibernate will distinct Provider and RetailCustomer from each
>   other if I don't have @Table annotation in their class?

If you don't specify table name using @Table, table will have same name as entity name.

> When I call providerRepository.findAll() how it will now which rows from 
>   "users"
>   table are provider and which are retailCustomer?

If selecting from ProviderRepository hibernate generates `inner join`. Only Provider entities will be returned. Hibernate generates native SQL:

```
select ... from Provider p
inner join User u on p.id=u.id
```

For selecting all users  with UserRepository hibernate will generate `left join`.  Result will contain all possible user types. Hibernate generates native SQL:

```
select ..., 
case 
when r.id is not null then 1 
when p.id is not null then 2 
when u.id is not null then 0 
end as clazz_0_ 
from User u
left outer join Provider p on p.id=u.id 
left outer join RetailCustomer r on r.id=u.id
```

`clazz_0_` helper column distinguishes which entity class will be created.

Comment: Thanks, so I will have 4 tables in that case. But what I don't understand is the fact that I don't know how table for entity Provider and RetailCustomer should look like. There are no new columns fo these entities, all the data for provider is already stored in "users" table. The same is for RetailCustomer. Only CorpotateCustomer have new, not common additional fields.

Comment: It will contain just ID column